# Recent activities tab does not show deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions, recent-activity

A question that I asked on Stack Overflow got closed and deleted because I misphrased my question to sound like it was not programming related.
According to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-can-a-question-or-answer-be-deleted/5222#5222) "the html address of a deleted question is still visible in your recent activities (recent tab)", but I don't see it listed there. I read on meta that the person who asked the question could still see the question if they had the URL.

Is the FAQ wrong or should this still be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a moderator or the community kills your question, it will not show up in your list of of questions unless you have at least 10,000 rep so that you can view deleted content.

There is always a little bit of confusion about who sees what content when we are dealing with deleted stuff. I am also not sure if that piece you quoted in the FAQ is completely accurate.

Comment: Do deleted questions or answers show up in 10K profiles?  I think not.

Comment: I have enough rep to see deleted content. But when I view my activity/comments, I don't see comments that I made in a question that was deleted by the author.